# Camera.current.ScreenPointToRay() returning different hit point than where mouse is clicked

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following code that attempts to place a gameObject at the position of a left mouse button click on the scene view in unity.  The code snippet is from a custom editor window.  I can't figure out why when I click the gameobject gets instantiated to the left and above of where I click.

```
 void CustomUpdate(UnityEditor.SceneView sv)
{
    Event e = Event.current;

    if ((e.type == EventType.MouseDrag || e.type == EventType.MouseDown) && e.button == 0)
    {
        if (PlaceObject)
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            Tools.current = Tool.Move;
            if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.current.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(e.mousePosition.x, Camera.current.pixelHeight - e.mousePosition.y, 0)),
                out hit, Mathf.Infinity, ~LayerMask.NameToLayer("Terrain")))
            {
                GameObject tee = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath("Assets/FSX Course Importer/Default Objects/Markers/TeeMarker/TeeMarker.prefab", typeof(GameObject)) as GameObject;
                GameObject go = Instantiate(tee) as GameObject;
                go.transform.position = hit.point;
                go.transform.SetParent(TeeParent);
                go.name = "Hole:" + HoleNumber + " Type:" + TeeType;
                e.Use();
                Undo.RegisterCreatedObjectUndo(go, "Undo placed Tee");
            }

            EditorWindow.GetWindow(typeof(CreateTeeWindow)).Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Have To Replace
`Physics.Raycast(Camera.current.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(e.mousePosition.x, Camera.current.pixelHeight - e.mousePosition.y, 0)`
With

```
Physics.Raycast(Camera.current.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition))
```

And Unity Will Take Care About All The Matrix

Comment: yes I tried that first of all, but it adds the gameobject even further away, even outside of the current sceneview frustrum

Comment: @ Chris Banwell is this on 3d world

Comment: @ Chris Banwell if it is on 3d world then try this  : `Vector3  mouseWorldPosition = Camera.current.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);` then use mouseWorldPosition as starting point of the ray and the currentCamera.transform.forward as direction

Comment: ok so I changed it to your suggestion @Chicken Games, but the mouseWorldPosition is always the same value regardless of where I click.  Debug log output (-569.6, 7.4, 208.2)  using `Vector3 mouseWorldPos = Camera.current.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
                Debug.Log(mouseWorldPos);
               
                if (Physics.Raycast(mouseWorldPos,Camera.current.transform.forward,
                    out hit, Mathf.Infinity, ~LayerMask.NameToLayer("Terrain")))
                {`

Comment: Just switched back to my original method and the debug log is telling me the click position is the same every time, this is getting wierd :) Here's the output of  `Debug.Log(Camera.current.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(e.mousePosition.x, Camera.current.pixelHeight - e.mousePosition.y, 0)));`  Origin: (-569.6, 7.4, 208.2), Dir: (-0.2, -1.0, 0.2)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)  it seems every click gives the same position and only the direction changes

Comment: It seems as it's an editor script you need to use the methods from HandleUtility.  Specifically  `Ray ray = HandleUtility.GUIPointToWorldRay(Event.current.mousePosition);
                RaycastHit hit;
                if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, ~LayerMask.NameToLayer("Terrain")))
                {
                    //code to place object at hit.point goes here
                }`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the updated code if anyone has a similar problem when working inside and editor window script

```
Ray ray = HandleUtility.GUIPointToWorldRay(Event.current.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, ~LayerMask.NameToLayer("Terrain")))
            {
                //code to place object at hit.point goes here
            }
```